# Getting min and max values from Pandas dataframe that uses d, w, m, y to represent days, weeks, months, years

Tags: python, pandas

So basically the data in a Pandas dataframe that I'm working with has a column that gives the time post-event. The data always follows the format # and then d, w, m, y to represent days, weeks, months, years (2 d, 17 w, etc). I'm trying to get the min and max values. Unfortunately because is difficult because of the differing units: 3 weeks is less than 2 months even though 2 is the smaller numbers, 150 weeks is longer than 1 year even though year is the bigger unit.

I though about implementing some complex code to convert everything into days and then rank them, but is there a better solution?

Just as an example, if I had a list of values that was 120 d, 3 w, 2 y, 15 m, and 14 d, how would I make a function that game me the min (in this case 14 d) and max (2 y)

Comment: Maybe you can convert the column to `pd.Timedelta` and then compare. For example `print(pd.Timedelta('17 w') > pd.Timedelta('2 d'))` is `True`

Comment: Could you please post  a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thanks Andrej. I'm going to mess with this for a bit to see if I can use this function. Rahul, I posted an example.

Answer (score 2):

Example how to convert string column to `pd.Timedelta`:

```
d = {'Time':['120 d', '3 w', '2 y', '15 m', '14 d']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['Time_td'] = df['Time'].map(pd.Timedelta)

print(df)

print('Min is', df['Time_td'].min())
print('Max is', df['Time_td'].max())
```

Prints:

```
    Time           Time_td
0  120 d 120 days 00:00:00
1    3 w  21 days 00:00:00
2    2 y 730 days 11:38:24
3   15 m   0 days 00:15:00
4   14 d  14 days 00:00:00
Min is 0 days 00:15:00
Max is 730 days 11:38:24
```